# How glue InDesign file with XML tags file on php language(or javascript)?

Tags: javascript, php, xml, adobe-indesign

I'm need export SQLdata to InDesign. Then i read documention and search library, but search library. XML simply export to InDesign,but how make it automatic with php or javascript?

Comment: What have you tried so far, we can help with specific problems but you seem to be asking for someone to do the whole thing for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking at a way of automatically placing xml content into a pre-tagged indesign document with PHP, you probably need InDesign Server and a script.